# How do i reload my dataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

im having some problems with reloading the dataTable plugin after insert data. I can do it if not using the dataTable jQuery plugin but i need to combine both.
Here is the code:

```
$('#tabela').DataTable({
   pageLength: 25,
   dom: 'Bfrtip'
});
```

When I insert the data I use:

```
$('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //stops page refresh
        $.ajax({
            url:"testes/insert.php", //file to insert data into DB
            method:"POST",
            data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#insert').val("Inserting");
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
                $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');
                $('#participantes_table').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Now my question is, how do I reload the data in the dataTable?

Best regards,
Fábio Peixeiro

EDIT:
I followed this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wDc47jcg0o

Comment: Please use the ajax.reload function https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: If you change your code so that you give the DataTable the AJAX details and make it load itself, then you can just call `ajax.Reload()`: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload(). If you stick with your current logic, you'll need to make the AJAX request again manually.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry, I just started using AJAX and dont know that much on how to use it, I've already tried using the `ajax.reload()` but nothing happens. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use datatable  function

```
var table = $('#tabela').DataTable()
    table.ajax.reload( null, false );
```

Comment: When i use this it shows an alert saying:
"DataTables warning: table id=tabela - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"

Answer (score 0):

I've used `table.draw()` to do this in the past.

> **Description**
>
> When you perform an action such as adding or deleting a
>   row, changing the sorting, filtering or paging characteristics of the
>   table you'll want DataTables to update the display to reflect these
>   changes. This function is provided for that purpose.

https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

So I think you can do the following:

```
var table = $('#tabela').DataTable({
   pageLength: 25,
   dom: 'Bfrtip'
});

$('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //stops page refresh

  $.ajax({
    url:"testes/insert.php", //file to insert data into DB
    method:"POST",
    data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),
    beforeSend:function(){
      $('#insert').val("Inserting");
    },
    success:function(data){
      $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
      $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');
      $('#participantes_table').html(data);
      table.draw(); // replace table with whatever your reference to the datatable is
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I might be missing something I dont know. I added the `.draw()´ and nothing happens

Comment: Please note I assigned `$('#tabela')` to `var table`. Use the developer console to debug any issues you encounter. In fact you should be able to run `$('#tabela').draw()` straight from the console.

Comment: Sorry but I dont get it, what do u mean to use the console? I am running this on xampp server and that's a php file running the data.

Comment: When you're using a web browser on a PC like Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox you have access to special developer tools that give you the ability to debug JavaScript running on the web page you're viewing. Read more here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/   https://developer.mozilla.org/son/docs/Tools

Comment: By console I meant javascript console that you can access via the browser's developer tools. If you ran `$('#tabela').draw()` directly from the javascript console it will interact directly with elements on the web page you're viewing

Comment: Hi again. I've just tested out what u adviced me and I got this error on the console. http://prntscr.com/fanb0u for what I can understand it is saying I that i don't have the .js file of DataTable library but I do right? http://prntscr.com/fankk3  http://prntscr.com/fankwm

Comment: Hi. The error in the first screenshot is stating that `$('#tabela')` is not initialised as a `DataTable`, which is what `$('#tabela').DataTable({...})` should be doing. Do you have any errors that show up in the console when the page loads? Check the console and network tabs they may give you some clues.

Comment: The only error I get from the console is caused by other .js - http://prntscr.com/faoh5w

Comment: If you start interacting with the datatable do you have any errors? For example you load the page and search for something? Also, the angular error may not be causing any issue but you would probably want to fix it just to be sure.

Comment: I can use the search box without any problems http://prntscr.com/faop5s I've also tried other function like .reload .etc and none seems to work

Comment: can u help me on skype?, this discussion is getting to long and i cant chat yet because i dont have enought reputation

Comment: Did u get the email?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax reload

> $('#myTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();